# Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, function, methods

I am trying to rewrite a VB function into C#, but I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1   Non-invocable member
>   'System.DateTime.Today' cannot be used
>   like a method.    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\daultrd\Local
>   Settings\Temp\SSIS\ST_ceaa126ff88343ccbfdc6dd27d8de1a7\ScriptMain.cs  56  67  ST_ceaa126ff88343ccbfdc6dd27d8de1a7

And the offending line:

```
strTomorrow = Convert.ToString(String.Format(DateTime.Today().AddDays(+1), "yyyyMMdd"));
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks guys; you are super quick!  And all of u said about the same thing.  So I removed the parenthesis but now I get a different error:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Format
>   (System.IFormatProvider, string,
>   params object[])' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Documents and
>   Settings\daultrd\Local
>   Settings\Temp\SSIS\2e23c9f006d64c249adb3d3a2e597591\ScriptMain.cs 56  44  st_ceaa126ff88343ccbfdc6dd27d8de1a7

And here is this line of code:

```
strTomorrow = Convert.ToString(String.Format(DateTime.Today.AddDays(+1), "yyyyMMdd"));   //Strings.Format(DateAndTime.Today().AddDays(+1), "yyyyMMdd"));
```

Comment: Your first reaction to any such problem should always be to check the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
strTomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

- String.Format always returns a string, there's no need to convert the result to a string
- String.Format does not accept a DateTime as its first argument. The easiest way to convert a DateTime to a string in a specific format is to call DateTime.ToString and pass the format as an argument

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much, Tom!  You are a superstar.

Comment: Not really, but I'm glad to help you out :-)

Answer (score 2):

`Today` is a property so you shouldn't add parentheses.  You also have the arguments to string.Format incorrect.

```
strTomorrow = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(+1));
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Format(System.IFormatProvider, string, params object[])' has some invalid arguments C:\Documents and Settings\daultrd\Local Settings\Temp\SSIS\2e23c9f006d64c249adb3d3a2e597591\ScriptMain.cs 56 44 st_ceaa126ff88343ccbfdc6dd27d8de1a7

Answer (score 1):

Change `DateTime.Today().AddDays(1)` to `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)`

Today is a property, not a method.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Today` is a property, not a method. Remove the parantheses.